# Run Query Quickly in Sql Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have two table in Sql server 2008 database file.first table have 102 column and second table contains 150 column.when i run one query in these table my query runs very very slow.(one table contains 10 million records)how can i fix this problem? how can i run queries very speed in this database?
what tips can i use?
please help me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimizing queries and database tuning is a large topic that can't be covered in a single answer.

The most probable cause is missing indices on the tables, but without knowing your database structure it is difficult to tell for sure.

A good starting point would be this article by Gail Shaw - [part 1](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/) and [part 2](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/).

Comment: Also: only select as many columns and rows from those huge tables as you **really** need